# Targeted Region of Interest Classification in eCognition

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, ecognition

Is there a method of targeting only specific areas for classification in eCognition? Say, maybe using pixel coordinate constraints?

Answer (score 1):

To generally subset your data at the initial step, when you load in your data, in the top right corner, there will be the option to select a spatial subset.
Through that, you can either choose it based on pixel coordinates, projected coordinates, or simply draw a box.

If you wish to work within a smaller area of an existing classification, you can assign the objects to a new class, or even transfer them to a different level using a simple Assign Class approach.
For this, the use of temporary classification classes are recommended.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of, after having completed a classification, targeting an area for further classification. Any ideas? Is there a way of bringing up the coordinates as you pan around on the screen?